# Flashing "Arduinos" In Production

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

So the issue I'm having revolves around programming a bunch esp8266 ESP-12 with ardunio code.

The main issue is that each esp8266 needs to have a token which allows it to authenticate with our server, however going through and changing `token = ___` each time requires a full recompile and takes almost a minute from start to finish (which is a lot when flashing 1000's of boards).

**In short** is there a simpler way to include run time vars that doesn't involve recompiling the whole thing?

Comment: What about using ESP Chip Id for it? But there must be some registration for it.

Comment: Exactly each token has to be hashed and stored on the server. Otherwise that would work perfect

Comment: Your server needs to know each token anyway, right? So, it doesn't really matter what the semantic value of the token is as long as it's unique to one device, doesn't change at runtime and is registered with the server?

Comment: Well it has to be registered prior to connection with the server which would add the layer of getting the chip Id off the board?

Comment: Sure, the SDK has `system_get_chip_id()` (which NodeMCU for example exposes as `node.chipid()`). If you can get the SDK with or without extra "layers" (Arduino, NodeMCU, etc.) onto the device you get access to the id. I'm sure you can add this to your build & deploy chain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ESP8266, but most MCUs you can do one or more of the following, depending whether the programmer allows programming parts of the flash separately or whether it has an externally programmable EEPROM:

- put the token in EEPROM and program as an additional step to flashing the program memory
- put it at a fixed memory location in program flash which is outside the main program, and program it as a second step using the offset for that location
- open the compiled hex, find the token's offset in program flash and program those bytes only as a second step overwriting the default after the program has been flashed
- open the compiled hex, find the token's offset, then before each module is flashed run a script to create a new hex with the token replaced, then program the flash in one go.
- use a good default for the token which will not otherwise occur in the hex, then before each module is flashed use a search and replace script to create a new hex with the token replaced, then program the flash in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the ID into EEPROM but if you inly want to flash one file (Flash content) you can use 
`static const uint32_t UniqueID __attribute__((section(".progmem"))) = 0x12345678;` but you will not know the address in flash and it may change when you recompile.
[PROGMEM reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)

You can also define a section to a known address in Flash (may be in the end of memory) I know this works with GCC but never tested in Arduino IDE.

`static const uint32_t UniqueID __attribute__((section(".mySection"))) = 0x12345678;`

Last solution is to simply define an address in the code where to read with `pgm_read_*`

The .hex file can then easily be modified with `srec_cat` to change the ID and then be flashed.
This can be used in production to give unique ID to each chip.